# how to navigate from MainPage.xaml to other page.

Tags: silverlight-4.0

In my apllication there are two from.The default form that is the MainPage.xaml and another form called login.xaml.
I have a button on MainPage.xaml,and my requirement is when the user click that button the Login page should be navigated.
This is my first experience in silverlight can i get that easily understandable code.

Answer (score 1):

```
this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Pagename", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
```

In this give your xaml or aspx (/Pagename) only no need to mention .xaml or .aspx

Answer (score 0):

Instead of navigating, you could use a [Childwindow](http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jprosise/archive/2009/04/29/silverlight-3-s-new-child-windows.aspx)

Otherwise, I think, you would have to use the Silverlight navigation framework, but this is quite complex. I'd suggest you to first have a child window pop up if you want to do something!

Answer (score 0):

On Button Event

```
this.Content=new Login();
```